# Как правильно вытаскивать дату из таблицы с помощью PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Нужно вытащить данные из таблицы. нашел код готовый. В таблице есть поле дата в формате 00.00.0000 но вытаскивает какую-то ерись 42066 типо того.

код такой:

require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

```
//создается экземпляр класса для чтения xls 
//$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();

//или XML XLS
//$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2003XML();

//или XLSX
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();

//подключаем файлик для чтения $xlsFile - путь до файла xls
$xlsFile = 'import.xlsx';
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($xlsFile);

//активный лист
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

//получаем количество строк в файле
$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();

//обход строк
for($row=1;($row<=$highestRow);$row++)
    {
        //получение значений ячеек в этой строке 

        $name = $objWorksheet->getCell("A".$row)->getValue();
        $email = $objWorksheet->getCell("B".$row)->getValue();
        $phone = $objWorksheet->getCell("C".$row)->getValue();
        $dataadd = $objWorksheet->getCell("D".$row)->getValue();
        $note = $objWorksheet->getCell("F".$row)->getValue();

        $name = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251",$name);
        $email = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251",$email);
        $phone = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251",$phone);
        $note = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251",$note);
        echo "".$name."/".$email."/".$phone."/".$dataadd."/".$note."<br>";

        //если у нас структура, то можем получить уровень строки 
        //для формирования дерева
        $lev=$objWorksheet->getRowDimension($row)->getOutlineLevel();

/*некоторые поставщики делают структуры с вложенностью свыше 8 уровня (0-7), 
это реализуется при помощи отступа (красной строки).*/   
$indent=$objWorksheet->getStyle('B'.$row)->getAlignment()->getIndent();


        /*тут уже ваши специфичные задачи, например импорт  данных в базу*/

    }

$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets(); //выгружаем листы после импорта
```

**Как решить проблему?**

Comment: код ничего не сообщает о проблеме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel хранит даты как число дней с 1 января 1900 года. Поэтому при
чтении ячейки с датой вы получаете 42066. В PHPExcel присутствует удобная функция
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(), которая превращает дату в формат
php.

После того как получили дату в `$dataadd`

```
$dataadd = date($format, PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($dataadd));
```

**Обновление**

Добавлять нужно ниже строчки

```
$dataadd = $objWorksheet->getCell("D".$row)->getValue();
```

Ну и из очевидного сделать require_once файла с классом `PHPExcel_Shared_Date` и в `$format` передавать требуемый формат даты

Comment: не работает. Это куда подставить чтобы работало.

Comment: Как проявляется что не работает, 500 ошибка или все так же продолжает число возвращать?

Comment: я просто не прописал формат даты. Все заработало.